# Why FilterBuilders.rangeFilter method changes dates in the range query?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, date-range

In `Es 1.1`, I'm trying to use the range filter for a date field with the following mapping :

```
"hiringDate": { "type": "date", "format": "dateOptionalTime" }
```

Surprisingly, the query being constructed by the following snippet changes the dates to the previous day for both the limits.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date startDate = df.parse("11-16-2014 00:00:00");
Date endDate = df.parse("11-18-2014 23:59:59");

FilterBuilder rangeFilter = FilterBuilders
                      .rangeFilter("dateOfJoining").from(startDate).to(endDate);
System.out.println(rangeFilter);
```

This is the output :

```
{
 "range" : {
    "hiringDate" : {
                "from" : "2014-11-15T18:30:00.000Z",
                "to" : "2014-11-18T18:29:59.000Z",
                "include_lower" : true,
                "include_upper" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Now my question is whether it's an expected behavior or I've done something wrong. Seems like the dates are changed to GMT time. Is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected as ElasticSearch is using UTC when displaying dates and the Java Date object is using the default timezone of your system.

To avoid this, you could set the timezone for your date parser

```
  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

To confirm, you can check org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.

Comment: proper solution, but I figured out another way. In my case dates were  inserted as strings which simply skips the UTC conversion, so during search I look for strings, eg :  `rangeFilter(field).from("11-16-2014").to("11-18-2014");`. It solves the problem.